# How do I create a black-bordered bubble window in Cocoa?

Tags: cocoa, user-interface, macos

I'm talking specifically about the kind you get if you click and hold on an app in the dock, or a folder if list view is enabled. Is it a menu style, or a window flag I can set like the brushed metal-style?

Lots of little free apps seem to use it. http://bambooapps.com/free-stuff/ is a good example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [MAAttachedWindow](http://mattgemmell.com/source/#maattachedwindow).